# How to configure ChannelInterceptor and extend AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer for access control in Spring Security 5.7?

Tags: java, spring, security, websocket

I am using Spring Security 5.7 and WebSocket in my application. I want to understand how to properly configure `ChannelInterceptor` and extend `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` to control access to WebSocket endpoints.

In Spring Security 5.7, what is the recommended approach for authorizing WebSocket messages? Should I create a custom `ChannelInterceptor` or extend `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`?

What are the differences between these two options and when should I use one vs the other?
Could you please point me to the relevant sections in the Spring Security reference documentation that covers this WebSocket authorization configuration? An example would also be very helpful to illustrate the key steps.

I inherited `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` and overrode `configureInbound()` to allow access to "/api/*" paths.

- I added a WebSocket endpoint "/api/chat/websocket" to handle received messages.
- This implemented basic access control and message handling.
  I tried to connect to the WebSocket endpoint "/api/chat/websocket" using Postman but still got a 403 Forbidden error.
- The request URL was "ws://localhost:8081/api/chat/websocket" using the Raw request method in Postman.
- Despite configuring access to "/api/*" paths in `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer`, the WebSocket connection was still blocked by Spring Security.

the previous configuration of `AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer` to allow "/api/*" did not seem to work for the WebSocket endpoint. More investigation is needed on why the access control rules defined in